# Given a finite union of arcs in the plane, are they ambiently isotopic to something with finite 1-dimensional Hausdorff measure?

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, arc-length, hausdorff-measure

We will be working with subsets of the plane $\Bbb R^2$. Some definitions:

An *arc* or a *Jordan arc* is an embedded copy of $[0,1]$ in the plane. The $1$-dimensional Hausdorff measure essentially gives you the "length" of a subset of a plane, and is defined in full generality [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_dimension). And an ambient isotopy between two subsets $A,B\subseteq\Bbb R^2$ is a map $F:[0,1]\times\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R^2$ such that $F_0$ is the identity map, each $F_t$ is a homeomorphism, and $F_1(A)=B$.

**Given a finite union of arcs in the plane, are they ambiently isotopic to something with finite 1-dimensional Hausdorff measure?**

Note that this isn't true if I upgrade it to countably many arcs, even if I force it to be compact, because I'm pretty sure the topologist's sine curve is the countable union of arcs and you can't make it have finite length through ambient isotopy.

If $A_i$, $1\le i\le n$ are my arcs and $K=\bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i$ is their union, I'm sort of imagining $K$ to look like it is filled with a whole lot of "bubbles" - like the Apollonian gasket, but hopefully more tame (the Apollonian gasket has Hausdorff dimension 1.3057). Crucially, the complement of $K$ might have infinitely many (bounded) components, which complicates things.

This feels like it *should* be true but is way too complicated for me to reason through. So... is it true?

Comment: I'm de-[Osgood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osgood_curve)ing my curves

Comment: Currently my benchmark for "how wild can the union of arcs be" is [this thing](https://i.imgur.com/kTy6aRS.png) (the union of _two_ arcs, if you're counting), but that's not so helpful in this case because both of those arcs have finite length

Comment: This is very likely to be true. However, it is also likely that a careful proof will be quite painful and long. Is there any specific reason you need this result?

Comment: @MoisheKohan I've been trying to get a better global feel for the set of possible solutions to [this question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/119012/79453), and this would sort-of put an upper bound to the possible complexity involved.